# Can positrons emit photons like electrons do?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

I am not asking about electron positron annihilation, nor positronium.

Electrons (when accelerated in some cases non-uniformly), could emit photons.

Though, I have not found any experiment that would do the same with accelerated positrons emitting photons. After the comments, there is brehmsstralung from positrons interacting with crystals.

I have read this question:

[Photon emission between an electron and positron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241667/)

[What happens if a photon emitted from an electron hits a positron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300187/)

But these do not answer my question.

[Does destructive interference occurs between lights emitted from matter and antimatter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362904/)

[Does the Advanced Photon Source use electrons or positrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178393/)

where DarioP says:

> A positron beam radiates exactly in the same way as an electron beam, so the physics is mostly the same except for one effect: the ion/electron cloud.

These ones state that antimatter can emit photons the same way as matter. Tough, there is no reference nor experiment.

We are able to produce positrons, maybe accelerate them, but I have not found any experiment that would do this or in any way see if positrons can emit photons.

Question:

1. Can positrons (when accelerated) emit photons?

Comment: Of course they do! People have built electron-positron collider. If positrons didn’t behave just as expected (i.e. just like electrons but with opposite charge) these machines wouldn’t have worked at _all_.

Comment: Are you just looking for an answer to your question at the end or are you looking for an *actually performed experiment* that tests this? It's not quite clear to me from the way your question is written.

Comment: LEP was an electron positron collider at high energies, reached 220 Gev the last years.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I was looking for an experiment, but the link in that cited question was broken to that experiment where they said positrons could be accelerated too. If it is obvious, then it is just me maybe, that I do not see exactly why the electron positron collider proves that positrons emit (real) photons, so real EM radiation, and not that there is a virtual photon exchange between the electron and the positron.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I might be misunderstanding, but even if somebody would be so kind to take the time and explain in detail why the electron positron collider proves that positrons can emit real EM radiation.

Comment: @knzhou I understand that the assumption is that antimatter is the same in every kind of way as matter (except charge), but the actual experiment (might be as well the collider), how exactly does the electron positron collision show real EM radiation emitted from the positron? Or is it that there is no experiment (because it is hard to do with positrons) and we just assume?

Comment: see this http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_045_02_0229.pdf ,brehmstrahlun spectra of electrons and positrons  measured in crystals. There are also a number of theoretical papers.

Comment: @annav I understand that we assume that antimatter is the same as matter, except charge, but is there something in the collider experiment that shows real EM radiation emitted from the positrons? Or do we just assume because positrons are hard to produce, accelerate and it is hard to show them actually emitting photons?

Comment: @annav thank you, "I might be misunderstanding, but even if somebody would be so kind to take the time and explain in detail why the electron positron collider proves that positrons can emit real EM radiation." Does this you think mean that they actually observed the real EM radiation from  (emitted by) positrons as they interacted with the crystal?

Comment: @annav do i understand correctly that in this case brehmstrahlung is considered as real EM radiation?

Comment: they used the electrons and separately the positrons to get the brehms spectra. These are different because there is no symmetry with the atoms. As far as colliders, if the two beams had different behavior in their synchrotron radiations it would be new physics, and it would show , because the two beams are travelling in opposite directions in the same turnnel wth the same magnets.. They obey the same calculations.

Comment: sure, brems spectra are measured

Comment: There is also the synchrotron radiation at the bending magnets. And the energy that needs to be supplied to keep the beams go around. Of course there is charge symmetry there.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no doubt that a positron can be accelerated with an electrical potential difference and that every acceleration is accompanied by a photon emission. One should be able to draw this conclusion from Anna's comment on the bremsstrahlung spectra of electrons and positrons.

But there is another point to think about. Accelerating electrons in an antenna rod, the emitted EM radiation is not only synchronized with their electric field direction but also with their magnetic field direction. At the moment, the positive direction of the electric field points upwards, the magnetic north pole points to the right (thumb up and the second finger to the right). What prevents the electrons to radiate lefthanded?
It is an asymmetricity which is not mentioned anywhere. Perhaps future research could show that positrons radiate left-handed.

Comment: "What prevents the electrons to radiate lefthanded?" The direction of the magnetic field is just by convention, because we use the right-hand rule. If we switched to the left-hand rule the magnetic field would flip in sign.

Comment: @knzhou If you take two vectors, perpendicular on each other, how many possibilities do you have to arrange them on a third vector, perpendicular to the first two? Do you agree, that you have exactly two possibilities? And about the conventions, they are conventions not to discuss anymore about the directions of electric nor magnetic fields. They are fixed. And beeng fixed, you can see, that exist two possibilities for the directions of the magnetic and the electric field in relation to the direction of propagation.

Comment: The problem is that the magnetic field is not a vector. It is a more abstract object (a rank 2 antisymmetric tensor) that should be visualized in terms of a plane. And when you take two vectors, perpendicular to each other, there is exactly one plane: the plane the vectors lie in.

Comment: @knzhou This doesn’t answer my questions. Secondly, I don’t care about is something a vector or not. As long as I may measure the direction of the magnetic field at some point and so I may do for the electric field, I’ll see that they form a right handed system. For radio waves you will not measure the left handed case.

Comment: If you think about the measuring devices you have for magnetic fields, you'll see that every single one of them includes an arbitrary sign convention that is ultimately tied to the choice of the right hand rule.

Comment: @knzhou That we are working in a cartesian system (which by convention is a right handed) is without any doubt. But see the two possibilities of electric to magnetic field directions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9ztN.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MiSB.png

Comment: @knzhou https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529644/electromagnetic-waves-are-the-two-chiral-options-possible